# Вопрос по как отправить GET запрос на другой хост JS

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли средствами JavaScript отправить get запрос на другой сервер, при этом не перезагружая страницу.

Comment: да, это возможно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключите jQuery и используйте [$.get](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("test.php");
```